# GGWordcloud with gradient color / transparent words (GGPlot Wordcloud gradient with adjustcolor)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, word-cloud, quanteda

I have created a wordcloud with `ggwordcloud`, because unfortunately I can't use alternative wordcloud packages. I was able to customize `ggwordcloud` to my requirements so far, only unfortunately I miss the implementation of a gradient that fades into transparent. So far I have not found a function that allows this.

The following code creates the `wordcloud`, but only with two colors, but I need a gradient, which goes more and more into the transparent (as in the 2nd code example), so that the smallest words are hidden / transparent.

```
library(ggwordcloud)
data("love_words_small")
data("love_words")

set.seed(42)
ggplot(
  love_words_small,
  aes(
    label = word, size = speakers,
    color = speakers
  )
) +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 24) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "darkred", high = "red")
```

The following implementation via the `quanteda` `Wordcloud` package has solved my problem so far using `adjustcolor`:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textplots)
set.seed(10)
dfmat1 <- dfm(corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, President == "Obama"),
              remove = stopwords("english"), remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
   dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 3)
col <- sapply(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), function(x) adjustcolor("#1F78B4", x))

textplot_wordcloud(dfmat1, adjust = 0.5, random_order = FALSE, 
                   color = col, rotation = FALSE)
```

Is there any way to transfer this solution to `ggwordcloud`?

[image]

Have many many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hi your quanteda code throws an error and it cannot be reproduced. Could you add the images about what you'd like to have?

Comment: Hi @s__! Sorry, I forgot the packages at the beginning. Now it should work. You find also an image attached.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution myself. It was so obvious...

```
col <- sapply(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), function(x) adjustcolor("#1F78B4", x))

library(ggwordcloud)
data("love_words_small")
data("love_words")

set.seed(42)
ggplot(
  love_words_small,
  aes(
    label = word, size = speakers,
    color = speakers
  )
) +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 24) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = col)
```